# Memory error problem while reading more than data file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, np

I need to read more than one waveform (about 62 seed file)
each of them has array length 17280000 and after append all files then concatenating them one one file. Finally, reshape the final array.

I'm using 32 Ram memory machine with 8 cores. Please, I want to fix the memory error message as attached on this pic .
[image]
Best Regards

Comment: could you give more details about the "waveform" data, what do you want to do? what is each array (with the ~17 M length) a training record?

Comment: I wanna reading large data-sets of seismic waves (17 M is a record of seismometer for 24 hours ) in order to train my auto-encoder model.

Comment: add the code next time, instead of a picture, you can copy jupyter notebook and add it

Comment: if a 24h wave is not a single training example, then split it and perform it in batches. look at Keras datagenerator classes

Comment: Have a look at numpy memmap, you are running out of RAM and this will allow you to have the numpy array stored using the disk as memory (but operate like a normal array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough memory in your computer to load that array, it's simply too big.

Think of it this way, an `int32` takes 24 bytes in Python and you are asking to load 4517769183 into memory, which is a little more than 144GB.

You could use NumPy's [`memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) functionality to store that file on your disk rather than in memory, but bear in mind the size of the resultant file!

You could also look into [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) or [theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano_versions/dev/index.html) which are both libraries designed for working with arrays like this bit by bit; only loading them into memory piece by piece.

Or you could manually read the data in pieces and train on each piece before discarding it and loading the next one.